# How to inform JAWS, VoiceOver or other assistive technology tools the DOM has been changed?

Tags: angular, accessibility, single-page-application, voiceover, jaws-screen-reader

I have an Angular project where the SPA renders the pages. But some pages load huge amount of datas, what takes a lot of time.

In normal cases the screen readers can handle a small daley in the data loading. But in this case the screen reader lost in space and I can't inform it the DOM has been changed.

I don't have affect on backend so I need to handle this problem on frontend side.

Is there any solution to inform assistive technology tools the DOM has been changed?

Comment: DOM updates are usually handled with either an ARIA live region or by managing focus. Depending on the use-case, it may also be appropriate to do neither. Your question is pretty vague, so I can't really provide more details without seeing your implementation.

Comment: I need to show list of datas. The data coming as JSON, but the JSON size is over a megabyte. I use live region to inform user "datas has been loaded", but the list I can't put into live region, because in first step I show only an extraction of most important infos. It'll be a list with a "show details" button. If the user hit the button, the DOM changes, and the live regio auto-reading starts again. And this is not a good practice, very annoying.

Comment: My tip is JAWS is fail on automatic DOM following if the presented DOM is too big, or the rendering takes too much time.

Comment: Based on this description, it sounds like you may be able to manage this with focus. As your data is loading, you could display some sort of visual indication of what's happening (like a "loading" gif with alt text) and set focus to that element. Then after loading is complete, you would presumably hide the gif and set focus to the list.

Comment: I've used this approach (suggested in comment above) before in conjunction with a live-region, although I did not load all data inside the live region. My page had an element that displayed the count and totals (e.g. "displaying 1-50 of 42,231 results") which I placed inside of a live region (polite). This can be useful for informing the visitor of changes to the data, with events like pagination, filtering or sorting.

Comment: I agree with @Josh's suggestion.  You could also update a live region with "still loading" if you want to monitor the loading of the JSON and update every 10 seconds or some interval.